# Is $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ a Fuchsian group of the first kind?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

We know that as a discrete subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb R)$, $PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is a Fuchsian group. But how to prove/disprove that it is of the first kind. i.e. if every point on the extended real line is its limit point of some orbit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Prove that every rational point on the real line is fixed by a parabolic element of $PSL(2,{\mathbb Z})$. A sub-hint: Think first about stabilizers of nonzero elements of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ in $SL(2,{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: I can prove that every rational point on the real line is fixed by a parabolic element of $PSL(2,{\mathbb Z})$, but I still can't find the orbit I need. Note that I need to fix *an* orbit with (subsequence) limit to any given point on $\mathbb R$, not just any rational number.

Comment: @NoOne: That's why it is only a hint. Now, try to prove that the fixed point if any parabolic element is a limit point. Maybe first consider the case when the parabolic element in question is $z\mapsto z+1$ and the fixed point is $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I can show that the orbit of $i$ under $PSL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ has infinity as its limit point. As a consequence any rational point on $\mathbb R$ is a limit point of an orbit... what then? I can't just approximate an irrational number with rationals. I need one orbit.

Comment: @NoOne: Well, then you are done, since the limit set is closed (can you prove this too?) and rational points are dense in $RP^1$ (I assume you know how to prove this as well).

Comment: that a limit set is closed is beyond my knowledge... so how to prove it?

Comment: @NoOne: An arbitrary topological space. If you took a general topology class, you already know that the accumulation set of any subset of a topological space is closed. My suggestion is to pick up a book covering Fuchsian groups (but **not** Katok's book) and read few chapters, at least covering limit sets and domains of discontinuity. (For instance, Beardon's  book is quite reasonable.)

Comment: I have to think hard about this. This is not the same as that the closure of an open set minus that open set is closed.

Comment: @NoOne: $Acc(A)=cl(A) - is(A)$ where $is(A)$ is the set of isolated points of $A$. Thus, you just need to prove that $is(A)$ is open in $cl(A)$.

Comment: @NoOne maybe you should edit you question to include what you can and can't prove and what your difficulties you are coming across.

Comment: @PaulPlummer I think I have figured it out and added some details below.

Answer (score 0):

Let's me add the following details to Moishe Kohan's answer and comments and please let me know if anything is wrong:

It is easy to see by Bezout theorem about coprime numbers that every rational point on $\mathbb R$ is $PSL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ equivalent to $\infty$. Since $\infty$ is a limit point of sequence $T^n z$ where $T:z\to z+1$. So $\mathbb Q \cup \infty$ is contained in the limit set of $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$.

Now here is the harder part:

Any irrational point $x\in \mathbb R$ can be approximated by a squence of rational numbers $(r_n)$. Although $(r_n)$ don't belong to the orbit $PSL(2,\mathbb R).i$, for each $n$, there exists a sequence $(g_{nk}.i)$ converging to $r_n$ as $k \to \infty$. Now the diagonal sequence $(g_{nn}.i)$ converges to $x$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: This is all correct, just I would not describe the 2nd part as "harder", people usually refer to this as a "standard diagonal sequence argument."

Comment: "Since $\infty$ is a limit point of sequence $T^n(i)$ where $T(z)=z+1$ $\ldots$." For students I think it would be very useful to explicitly describe the basis of open sets which defines the topology of the sphere at-infinity with respect to $\bf{H}$. For example, I consider open horoballs centred at infinity as the natural open sets defining the topology of the boundary at-infinity, except $T^n(i)$ diverges with respect to this topology. But Busemann is not the usual topology. So again for students, it needs to be explicit: what is an open neighborhood of the ideal point $\infty$ ?